# Quasar table form for each row

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a table as the one below. 1, 2 and 3 are existing entries. 4 is a  containing input forms to add new entries.

As of now, the entire table is wrapped by a , which is a bad solution. However, if I put a  inside the , the table doesn't render.

What I want to achieve is to have one form for each row. Is this possible somehow?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @vchan I have tried having a form inside the table component, which crashes the table. And as mentioned, the "working" solution is to have the entire table wrapped in a form.

However, I think I will use Vuelidate for this. I guess it will solve my issue :)

Comment: @ChrisEikrem Plz add some code as well or sample codepen plz